# How to get response from invoking Azure Function in release pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I need to use the response body from my agentless invoke azure function job in another job. The version of ADO I'm using doesn't allow me to directly edit the YML, but I can read the yml.

Is the response saved in a pipeline variable? Is there a way to save it? Alternatively, I can make the request with the inline PowerShell job.

```
variables:
  adoazurekey: 'spooky-scary-secret'

steps:
- task: AzureFunction@1
  displayName: GetBodyResponse
  inputs:
    function: 'example.com'
    key: '$(adoazurekey)'
    method: GET
    queryParameters: 'stage=$(stage)'
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?